# Gravitational field strength and potential different signs

Tags: newtonian-gravity, potential-energy, conventions

In my revision guide the gravitational field strength is given as $g=GM/r^2$ whereas gravitational potential is $V=-GM/r$. Why does potential have a minus sign but field strength doesn't?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/64260/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of a convention wherein zero gravitational potential is said to be at infinity. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_potential#Mathematical_form):

$V(x) = \frac{W}{m} = \frac{1}{m} \int\limits_{\infty}^{x} F \ dx = \frac{1}{m} \int\limits_{\infty}^{x} \frac{G m M}{x^2} dx = -\frac{G M}{x}$

*"By convention, it is always negative where it is defined, and as x tends to infinity, it approaches zero."*

One could define zero potential to be at sea level, but that would be sea level on Earth, at say the equator. It isn't ideal. Hence the convention to define the zero to be at infinity. That isn't ideal either.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. I think there should be a minus sign and it doesn't matter where you set the zero of potential.

Gravitational field strength is the negative gradient of the potential.

For a spherically symmetric field
$$ g(r) = -\frac{dV}{dr}.$$

If 
$$V = -\frac{GM}{r} + V_0,$$
where $V_0$ is an arbitrary constant, then 
$$g = -\frac{GM}{r^2}.$$

i.e. your book is incorrect or more fairly what it calls the *strength* of the gravitational field, is its *magnitude*. The gravitational field is a vector, and the negative sign indicates that its direction is towards decreasing $r$.

Potential on the other hand is a scalar, and has no direction. You can add any constant to it and you have the same gravitational field. In this case the convention is to add nothing, meaning that the zero of potential is at infinite $r$.

Answer (score 0):

Potential has a negative sign as work has to be done against the external force to bring the mass from infinity to the point (definition of potential )